# Can i use ESP32 3.3V pwm on MG90D Servo

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, servo, esp32, robotics

Ok so, im building the eletronical part of a sumo robot for my university team, and i came to a barrier, on past researchs we came to the conclusion that using MG90D servo is the best option for us (but we used PIC18F back) nowdays we are using ESP32, so especifically my problem is in the signal pin on the servo, he's powered by a range of 4.8V DC or 6V DC, do i need to use a PWM of similar voltage to rotate the servo?

Some other info here:

- The datasheet i found is kinda useless for me. Here's the link: http://media.digikey.com/pdf/data%20sheets/adafruit%20pdfs/1143_web.pdf
- Im accepting other servos sugestions too.
- In a random website that was selling this MG90D, it said the servo is digital.

Comment: In the absence of hard data, just use a means of level shifting like a 74hct08 or similar unless there are specific reasons you want to cut corners?

Comment: this may help ... https://www.princeton.edu/~mae412/TEXT/NTRAK2002/292-302.pdf ... and this ... https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/hobby-servo-tutorial/all

Comment: you can run a test ... use a 4.7 kΩ resistor between the ESP32 pin and the servo control pin